# iOS crash on setting navigation items

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have a UIButton that on the touchdown event pops a `UIViewController` to view. In the `viewDidLoad`, the app is crashing with an Exception of:

> -[UILabel stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16674e30

Here is the code causing the crash:

```
viewController.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
UIImage *logo = [UIImage imageNamed:backgroundImageName];
UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
logoView.image = logo;
logoView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);
viewController.navigationItem.titleView = logoView; // crash at this line
```

The last line is the one that causes a crash. I'm using SWRevealController as a slide left drawer style menu. I have 5 other `UIViewControllers` using the exact same code and working properly but I can't find any difference between them and the other classes. I know this might seem kinda vague but I'm not sure where to come at this issue now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the stack at the crash on the main thread:

```
#0  0x378416a0 in objc_exception_throw ()
#1  0x2d4e47b6 in -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] ()
#2  0x2d4e30ae in ___forwarding___ ()
#3  0x2d431dc8 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#4  0x2fcfc78e in -[UINavigationItem initWithTitle:] ()
#5  0x2fcfc6dc in -[UIViewController(UINavigationControllerItem) navigationItem] ()
#6  0x00110b94 in -[CSUtility addleftButtonToNavItem:rightButton:background:rightButtonTitle:forViewController:revealViewController:overrideLeft:] at /Users/shawn/Documents/TruthIt/TruthIOS/TruthiOS/TruthiOS/CSUtility.m:59
#7  0x0012cd92 in -[CSQuestionDetailViewController viewDidLoad] at /Users/shawn/Documents/TruthIt/TruthIOS/TruthiOS/TruthiOS/CSQuestionDetailViewController.m:227
#8  0x2fc6995a in -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] ()
#9  0x2fc69718 in -[UIViewController view] ()
#10 0x2fdf5c2a in -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] ()
#11 0x2fd13a16 in -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] ()
#12 0x2fd13820 in -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] ()
#13 0x2fd137b8 in -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] ()
#14 0x2fc65352 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] ()
#15 0x2f8eb942 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
#16 0x2f8e7166 in CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#17 0x2f8e6ff8 in CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#18 0x2f8e6a0c in CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) ()
#19 0x2f8e681e in CA::Transaction::commit() ()
#20 0x2f8e054c in CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) ()
#21 0x2d4abf68 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#22 0x2d4a98f6 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#23 0x2d4a9c42 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#24 0x2d414470 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#25 0x2d414252 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#26 0x321482ea in GSEventRunModal ()
#27 0x2fcc9844 in UIApplicationMain ()
#28 0x00111d7c in main at /Users/shawn/Documents/TruthIt/TruthIOS/TruthiOS/TruthiOS/main.m:16
```

This is kinda interesting, if I switch the view code to the `viewWillAppear` I still get the crash just not from my code. Here's that stack trace:

```
Thread 1, Queue : com.apple.main-thread
#0  0x378416a0 in objc_exception_throw ()
#1  0x2d4e47b6 in -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] ()
#2  0x2d4e30ae in ___forwarding___ ()
#3  0x2d431dc8 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#4  0x2fcfc78e in -[UINavigationItem initWithTitle:] ()
#5  0x2fcfc6dc in -[UIViewController(UINavigationControllerItem) navigationItem] ()
#6  0x2fd1559a in -[UINavigationController _hasTranslucentNavigationBarIncludingViewController:] ()
#7  0x2fd1542c in -[UINavigationController _shouldNavigationBarInsetViewController:orOverlayContent:] ()
#8  0x2fd14c3e in -[UINavigationController _frameForViewController:] ()
#9  0x2fdf5c48 in -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] ()
#10 0x2fd13a16 in -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] ()
#11 0x2fd13820 in -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] ()
#12 0x2fd137b8 in -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] ()
#13 0x2fc65352 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] ()
#14 0x2f8eb942 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
#15 0x2f8e7166 in CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#16 0x2f8e6ff8 in CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#17 0x2f8e6a0c in CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) ()
#18 0x2f8e681e in CA::Transaction::commit() ()
#19 0x2f8e054c in CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) ()
#20 0x2d4abf68 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#21 0x2d4a98f6 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#22 0x2d4a9c42 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#23 0x2d414470 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#24 0x2d414252 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#25 0x321482ea in GSEventRunModal ()
#26 0x2fcc9844 in UIApplicationMain ()
#27 0x00124cf4 in main at /Users/shawn/Documents/TruthIt/TruthIOS/TruthiOS/TruthiOS/main.m:16
```

Ok Thanks for the idea rmaddy I think you are on to something but I still didn't get it quite all the way there yet. I (stupidly I know, I'm coding in a hurry here) had a UILabel defined as with the name title. I changed that to questionTitle and now I'm receiving a different error -[UILabel copyWithZone] unrecognized selector sent to instance, once more here is the stack trace:

```
    Thread 1, Queue : com.apple.main-thread
#0  0x378416a0 in objc_exception_throw ()
#1  0x2d4e47b6 in -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] ()
#2  0x2d4e30ae in ___forwarding___ ()
#3  0x2d431dc8 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#4  0x2fcfb9a8 in -[UIViewController setTitle:] ()
#5  0x2de203b6 in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] ()
#6  0x2de31ffc in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] ()
#7  0x2d4507e8 in -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] ()
#8  0x2ffc44de in -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] ()
#9  0x2ff260fa in -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] ()
#10 0x2fd87b58 in -[UIViewController loadView] ()
#11 0x2fc6979c in -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] ()
#12 0x2fc69718 in -[UIViewController view] ()
#13 0x2fdf5c2a in -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] ()
#14 0x2fd13a16 in -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] ()
#15 0x2fd13820 in -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] ()
#16 0x2fd137b8 in -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] ()
#17 0x2fc65352 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] ()
#18 0x2f8eb942 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
#19 0x2f8e7166 in CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#20 0x2f8e6ff8 in CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#21 0x2f8e6a0c in CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) ()
#22 0x2f8e681e in CA::Transaction::commit() ()
#23 0x2f8e054c in CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) ()
#24 0x2d4abf68 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#25 0x2d4a98f6 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#26 0x2d4a9c42 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#27 0x2d414470 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#28 0x2d414252 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#29 0x321482ea in GSEventRunModal ()
#30 0x2fcc9844 in UIApplicationMain ()
#31 0x0008cccc in main at /Users/shawn/Documents/TruthIt/TruthIOS/TruthiOS/TruthiOS/main.m:16
```

Comment: Tried a cmd-shift-k? Also, tried wrapping your image view in a view?

Comment: Yep I just tried again and no dice. :(

Comment: Can you post your stack?

Comment: put this code inside viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad

Comment: Ok I added the stack trace. I'm try and put it in viewWillAppear but it is in viewDidLoad on all the other view controllers so I'll be really suprised.

Comment: You have said button but i don't see the button.

Comment: i didnt understand what is viewController? why dont u use self instead of viewController?

Comment: Both crashes are happening when the view controller's `navigationItem` is lazy loaded. It appears that somehow the navigationItem's title (which should be an `NSString`, is actually an `UILabel`. Do you have a `title` property in this view controller with a type of `UILabel` or did you implement a `title` method that is returning a `UILabel` instead of a string?

Comment: Rmaddy good catch, I changed the property name and now I have a different error. It's progress. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: What's the new error that goes with the new stack trace?

Comment: Oops sorry it's unrecognized selector sent to instance [UILabel copyWithZone]

Comment: It's looks like the same basic problem but now you are assigning a `UILabel` to the `title` property or calling the `setTitle:` method with a `UILabel` instead of a string.

Comment: Are you loading the label from a nib?

Comment: It's definitely something wrong with your story board. You've set the title of the navigationItem to a UILabel. Please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the stacktrace, it looks like you are trying to create a new navigation item with initWithTitle:, but you are passing a UILabel to the initializer instead of an NSString. Maybe you want to pass the value of the label to the initializer instead? Check

```
[CSUtility addleftButtonToNavItem:rightButton:background:rightButtonTitle:forViewController:revealViewController:overrideLeft:] at /Users/shawn/Documents/TruthIt/TruthIOS/TruthiOS/TruthiOS/CSUtility.m:59
```